# Java Look and Feel Nimbus only work in a new window

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, nimbus

I'm creating gui using the "UI Designer" in IntelliJ.

I set the theme to "Nimbus" unfortunately it does not work on the main window. Works only new windows / dialogs.

Screen for window and application:

[image]

Comment: Showing your code would help us help _you_

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work on the main window, or only that it doesn't work on the main window *before you restart your program*?

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the look and feel before you instantiate components such as your `gui` class (and you should capitalize class names).

Answer (score 4):

I recommend moving Look&Feel configuration into launching main function before doing anything else. Changes to L&F affect only new frames, old ones need to be updated.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    try {
                for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                    if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                        javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
    //Launching frames
    }
```

Netbeans way to set L&F, with is quite nice.
If you changing L&F at runtime, you have to update existing objects (like your fist windown, that don't have Numbus look)

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(stringName);
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame); //quite often "this" passed in 
frame.pack();
```